# Woocommerce: Show all products excluding what contains cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display all available products excluding what currently is in the cart. I have try to use some methods found over the internet but most of them use filters so I'm not able to exclude what contains cart.

My example code to display all products in stock looks like:

```
    <?php
    $params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 999,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                        'key' => '_stock_status',
                        'value' => 'instock'
                    )
        )
    );

    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);

?>

<ul>
<?php
  if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
      $wc_query->the_post();
      $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
?>
  <li>
  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php
    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_excerpt();
    echo $product->get_price_html();
    echo $product->get_sku();
?>
  </li>

<?php
    endwhile; 

  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  else:
?>
  <li>
  <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
  </li>

  <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Any tips how to get it to work? Only one thing comes to my mind - to check against SKUs from the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got is solved:

```
global $woocommerce; 
$my_cart = array();

$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
//print_r($values); 
$_product = $values['data']->post;

$my_cart[] = $_product->ID;
}

//print_r($my_cart);

$params = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 999, 
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => '_stock_status',
      'value' => 'instock'
      )
  ) 
);

$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);

?>

<ul>

<?php

  if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
      $wc_query->the_post(); 
      $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); 


if (!in_array($product->id, $my_cart)){
?>

<li>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php 

    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_excerpt();
    echo $product->get_price_html(); 
    echo $product->get_sku();
    echo $product->id;

?>

<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="quantity">
          <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="9" name="quantity" value="1" title="<?php _e('Szt.', 'my-theme'); ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
     </div>  
     <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr($product->id); ?>">
     <button type="submit"> <?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?> </button>
</form>


</li>



<?php 
}

    endwhile; 

    wp_reset_postdata(); 

    else:  
?>
<li><?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>

</ul>
```